# delete item from child array without effect on parent array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code

```
$scope.airLineFilter = function ("jai") {
$scope.Names=["sai","ram","jai","kiran","radha"];
      $scope.airLinesFilterData = $scope.Names;
      var airLinedata = $scope.airLinesFilterData.indexOf(data);
      if (airLinedata > -1) {
          $scope.airLinesFilterData.splice(airLinedata, 1);
      } else {
           $scope.airLinesFilterData.push(data);
      }
  };
```

If we remove the "jai" then it will remove in "$scope.airLinesFilterData" not delete in "$scope.Names".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you are not passing the parameter to airLineFilter, insted you are directly giving the string value in that function.That is wrong. also what is that data which you have mentioned inside indexOf method? I have changed your function as below.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.airLineFilter = function (value) {
    $scope.Names=["sai","ram","jai","kiran","radha"];
      $scope.airLinesFilterData = angular.copy($scope.Names);
      var airLinedata = $scope.airLinesFilterData.indexOf(value);
      if (airLinedata > -1) {
          $scope.airLinesFilterData.splice(airLinedata, 1);
      } else {
           $scope.airLinesFilterData.push(value);
      }
  };
    $scope.airLineFilter("jai");
});
```

In this i am calling the airLineFilter and i am passing 'Jai' as value to that function.Now it will remove 'jai' from $scope.airLinesFilterData array and it will not remove value from $scope.Names. I have used angular.copy();

Please see this js fiddle example also. http://jsfiddle.net/dprtrj2v/

Thanks

Comment: Hi,Avinash,The above code Names deleting "$scope.airLinesFilterData" and "$scope.Names",I don't want to delete in "$scope.Names".

Comment: I have edited the code again. Don't directly assign the $scope.Names to $scope.airLinesFilterData. Insted i have used angular.copy. which will create the copy of that variable. so that it will not delete the value in $scope.Names.